# Rear wheel spinning causes pedals to jolt forward when not pedalling

Tags: cassette, freehub

I've recently replaced my cassette and chain on my bike and I've found that now when the rear wheel is spinning freely (no pedalling) it will often cause the chain to suddenly jolt forward. I'm not entirely sure what this is - I think I could have overtightened the cassette, but it didn't seem particularly tight and I haven't found anything online suggesting this as being a common symptom of over tight cassettes? Does anyone have any ideas as to what this could be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like your freehub is sticking. Overtightening the cassette wouldn't cause that on any I've worked on, but it's conceivable that a too-thick locknut could cause some binding.

If you put the bike on a stand (or upside-down) does the wheel spin as freely as normal, until it jumps? Listen to the clicking of the freehub as the wheel spins. Is it even? Does it stop when it misbehaves? The latter might be hard to hear with the chain making a noise.

Comment: Thank you - I've tried spinning the wheel freely and it sounds normal to me until it clicks. When it jumps it sounds like it stops engaging. Once it's jumped if I stop the wheel spinning and try to rotate the pedal back it doesn't tend to want to go back, I just get a lot of slack in the chain?

Comment: That slack also sounds like a sticking freehub, though a misaligned derailleur can lead to funny things if you backpedal a lot.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see what I can do about getting it unstuck and see if that helps. If that is the case, would it be likely that this is just coincidental with me replacing the cassette? Or is there something I might have done which could have caused the issue (just to keep an eye out for in future!)

Comment: I wouldn't totally rule out you having jammed it somehow. Try loosening the lockring for a test, and if that helps, try the old lockring. I bought a cheap cassette and couldn't use its lockring because it went in too deep and pressed the seal into the bearings - so used a spare/old shimano lockring